# Error inflating class RingtonePreference

Tags: android, android-inflate

I was trying to repeat an example from a book, whose source code has been tested on the very same phone, which works, but mine didn't. I have compared the source codes and they are exactly the same.

Errors are:

```
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): Process: org.crazyit.app, PID: 20354
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.crazyit.app/org.crazyit.app.PreferenceActivityTest}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class RingtongPreference
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class RingtongPreference
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at org.crazyit.app.PreferenceActivityTest$Prefs1Fragment.onCreate(PreferenceActivityTest.java:54)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1688)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:860)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1450)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5284)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    ... 11 more
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.RingtongPreference" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.crazyit.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.crazyit.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
04-05 15:30:33.004: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    ... 24 more
```

The XML file containing RingtonePrefrences is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <RingtongPreference
            android:ringtoneType="all"
            android:title="Ringtone Settings"
            android:summary="Choose Ringtones(Test RingtonePrerference)"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:key="ring_key"
            android:showSilent="true">
        </RingtongPreference>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Personal Info">
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="name"
                android:title="Please fill in your username"
                android:summary="Please fill in your username(Test EditTextPreference)"
                android:dialogTitle="Your username："/>
            <ListPreference
                android:key="gender"
                android:title="Gender"
                android:summary="Gender(Test ListPreference)"
                android:dialogTitle="ListPreference"
                android:entries="@array/gender_name_list"
                android:entryValues="@array/gender_value_list"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="System Settings">
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="autoSave"
                android:title="AutoSave"
                android:summaryOn="AutoSave: On"
                android:summaryOff="AutoSave: Off"
                android:defaultValue="true"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

And Activity to inflate the xml is:

```
package org.crazyit.app;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PreferenceActivityTest extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(hasHeaders())
        {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText("Settings");
            setListFooter(button);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
    {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }

    public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
    public static class Prefs2Fragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.display_prefs);
            String website = getArguments().getString("website");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                    website, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case, I will include the AndroidManifest here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.crazyit.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity
    android:name=".OtherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ExpandableListActivityTest"
    android:label="See Categories">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".PreferenceActivityTest"
    android:label="Settings">
</activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried to look for the bug throughout the whole afternoon without finding it out. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have a `RingtongPreference`, which is what your preference XML is asking for. My guess is that this is a typo, and you mean `RingtonePreference`, as in your question title.